# How do I loop through all non-filtered rows in XamDataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a XamDataGrid with record filtering allowed. The first field is a "Selected" checkbox and the rest are just the data from the objects I display in the grid. In terms of code it looks something like this:

```
<igWPF:XamDataGrid x:Name="xamDataGrid" 
                   DataSource="{Binding SomeDataSourceInTheViewModels}">
    <!-- XamDataGrid Settings -->
    <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <igWPF:FieldLayoutSettings FilterAction="Hide"
                                   FilterUIType="LabelIcons"/>
    </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
    <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
        <igWPF:FieldSettings ...
                             AllowRecordFiltering="True"
                             FilterOperatorDefaultValue="Equals"
                             FilterLabelIconDropDownType="MultiSelectExcelStyle"
                            .../>
    </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>

    <!-- XamDataGrid Field layout -->
    <igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        <igWPF:FieldLayout>
            <igWPF:Field Label="Selected" Name="Selected" Width="Auto">

                <!-- Select/Unselect all button -->
                <igWPF:Field.Settings>
                    <igWPF:FieldSettings AllowEdit="True">
                        <igWPF:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:LabelPresenter}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type igWPF:LabelPresenter}}">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:LabelPresenter}">
                                            <!-- The Select all checkbox -->
                                            <CheckBox /> 
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </igWPF:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle>
                    </igWPF:FieldSettings>
                </igWPF:Field.Settings>
            </igWPF:Field>

            <!-- The rest of the fields -->
            <igWPF:Field Label="SomeIntValue" Name="SomeIntValue" Width="Auto"/>
            <igWPF:Field Label="SomeBoolValue" Name="SomeBoolValue" Width="Auto" />
            <igWPF:Field Label="SomeStringValue" Name="SomeStringValue" Width="Auto" />
        </igWPF:FieldLayout>
    </igWPF:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
</igWPF:XamDataGrid>
```

My end goal is to have a checkbox on the top of the datagrid above the `Selected` column where I can click and select all non-filtered rows. I'm open to new ideas on how to implement this, but my question is: how can I loop through all the non-filtered rows in code-behind or in ViewModel?

I know there is an "IsFilteredOut" property somewhere but can't find it in `xamDataGrid`

Comment: Did you look in the "SomeDataSourceInTheViewModels" property that you bind to? This should contain all unfiltered items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *GetFilteredOutDataRecords()* method of the ***RecordManager*** returns all data records that do not pass record filter conditions:

```
foreach(var rec in xamDataGrid.RecordManager.GetFilteredOutDataRecords())
{
  // TODO: ...
}
```

Hope that helps.